# Liferay ADT - Open Asset in a own page

Tags: url, liferay, adt, freemarker, liferay-7

In an ADT, there's a variable called viewUrl: It opens the asset inside of the AssetPublisher. Now what i want is, to open the Asset **not just inside** the AssetPublisher but in a new Page.. So the asset is the only thing on the page and not just between all the other webcontents.

Are there some parameters wich allow to do this?

PS: I'm using Liferay 7 and the ADT is written in Freemarker.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your asset a web content? If it is, you could consider using a webcontent display instead of the publisher, and this portlet to a page with a unique column .. Then using the friendly url that is show in the configuration section of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the display in context setting in your asset publisher. In this case, it tried to find the best page to show the asset. I can’t explain the "best page" algorithm as it seems to differ from asset to assets. But it usually tried to show the asset where it is shown out of an asset publisher.

In the particular case of a web content, you can use the "display page" setting in the web content. For that you have to configure a page with an asset publisher that has selected the checkbox "Set as the Default Asset Publisher for This Page". Then in your web content you can set the chosen page as display page.

In your ADT you shouldn’t have anything more to do as the viewUrl should automatically direct to the new page. If you don’t want to manually set the display page on every web content creation, you can edit the structure default values to set the display page. In liferay 7 you can even set the default value for the basic web content.

you can have more detailed info on the liferay doc: https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/publishing-assets#content-display-pages